# How to spread out the contents of an array evenly and fill in the empty slots with a certain value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have 3 inputs: an array, a total count integer and an arbitrary value.

```
input_array = ['hello', 'there', 'world']
total_count = 15
fill_value = null
```

Desired output:

```
output = [
  'hello',
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   'there',
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   'world',
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
]
```

Assume that the length of `input_array` does not exceed `total_count`. Other scenarios:

- If `total_count` was `3`, you'd get `['hello', 'there', 'world']`
- If `total_count` was `4`, you'd get `['hello', null, 'there', 'world']`
- etc. etc.

This feels like a candidate for a recursive function? You could take `Math.ceil((total_count - input_array.length) / input_array.length)` and use that value to fill in the slots but I'm not sure what the cleanest syntax would look like.

Comment: I would use a prefilled array `Array.fill(total_count, fill_value)` and a loop/`forEach`, no recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#flatMap` to construct the final array.

```js
function createArr(initial, count, fill) {
  const each = Math.floor(count / initial.length) - 1, rem = count % initial.length;
  return initial.flatMap((x, i) => [x, ...Array(each + (i < rem)).fill(fill)]);
}
console.log(createArr(['hello', 'there', 'world'], 15, null));
console.log(createArr(['hello', 'there', 'world'], 4, null));
console.log(createArr(['hello', 'there', 'world'], 3, null));
```

Comment: nice use of flatMap

Answer (score 0):

The trick is figuring out where the items go. If the number of elements does not fit the output array evenly, every index will be pushed right by one for each previous item to evenly distribute the overhead:

```js
function fillPadded(arr, count, fillWith){
  const filled = Array(count).fill(fillWith)
  const step = Math.floor(count/arr.length)
  const offs = count%arr.length
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    const pos = i*step + (i <= offs ? i : offs) // or Math.min(i, offs)
    filled[pos] = arr[i]
  }
  return filled
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(fillPadded(['hello', 'there', 'world', 'foo'], 9, null)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(fillPadded(['hello', 'there', 'world', 'foo'], 10, null)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(fillPadded(['hello', 'there', 'world', 'foo'], 11, null)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(fillPadded(['hello', 'there', 'world'], 15, null)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```